# How to align a column in pgfplotstable on the dot of the scientific notation?

Tags: pgfplotstable

When I try to align values in a pgfplots table, I get problems when the exponent in the scientific notation has more digits.

Currently I am using the style:

```
columns/0/.style={column type={r},column name=\makecell{Column 0},sci,sci 10e,precision=3, column type/.add={}{@{\hspace{1em}}}},
```

I now get a problem when I have values like

```
1.1234 · 10⁹
 1.12 · 10¹¹
```

Without right align I get

```
1.1234 · 10⁹
1.12 · 10¹¹
```

What I would like to have is

```
1.1234 · 10⁹
  1.12 · 10¹¹
```

Or maybe padding with zeros

```
1.1234 · 10⁹
1.1200 · 10¹¹
```

Example Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/1/.style={column type={r},sci,sci 10e,precision=3, column type/.add={}{@{\hspace{1em}}}},
    col sep=&,
    row sep=\\,
]{
    1 & 1234000000   \\
    2 & 120000000000 \\
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, share a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)!

Comment: @NBur It's done

Answer (score 1):

You can use the column S type from siunitx.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % Formats the units and values
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage[hang,bf,small]{caption}
\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/1/.style={column type={r},sci,sci 10e,precision=3, column type/.add={}{@{\hspace{1em}}}},
  col sep=&,
  row sep=\\,
  ]{
    1 & 1234000000   \\
    2 & 120000000000 \\
  }

  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  columns/1/.style={column type={S[
      round-mode=places,
      round-precision = 3,
      exponent-mode = scientific,
      drop-zero-decimal=true,
      table-format=1.3e1,
      ]}},
  col sep={&},
  row sep={\\},
  header=false,
  ]{
    1 & 1234000000   \\
    2 & 120000000000 \\
  }
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I now use the `sci,sci zerofill,sci 10e` style with left aligned colums `column type={l}`. It aligns the dots, as now all numbers left of them have the same length.